# Query to save 10 fields

Tags: nodes, entities

Using Drupal 7, I created a node with the 10 fields; these fields are inserted as a table.

What query can I use insert the field values to the multiple tables, since multiple tables are the multiple fields?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple tables are the multiple fields."?

Comment: You should not worry about the query to use, normally, as Drupal saves the fields for you, if you are using the node edit form.

Answer (score 2):

Use the API: node_save().

Saving data directly to field tables is not possible, you shouldn't even consider this. There are many ways to import data into nodes, for example the Migrate or Feeds modules, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about the query to use, normally, as Drupal saves the fields for you, if you are using the node edit form.

If you are not using the node edit form, you should use the functions Drupal provides to save entities, such as [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) for nodes, or [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) for user objects.

The reason you should not save field data directly in the database is that there is an API for field storage: the [Field Storage API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/group/field_storage/7). The default field storage module uses the local SQL database to implement these operations, but that could not be true for other implementations of the field storage; this is what happens with the MongoDB field storage module, part of the [Mongodb](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) project.
Drupal doesn't take assumptions about the field storage, and so should your code.